# Scale position on weighted vector

Tags: logic, algorithms

I have a logic problem in a software I'm writing that I can't identify a way to resolve. Maybe it's just simple math and I'm overthinking.

In this software, the user select several colours in a discrete set of colours. There are 7 specific colours and the user must select one color for each of 7 categories (it's a 7x7 matrix selection).

What I need to do now is to "average" the user selection in a scale of 0.0 to 1.0 - that represents a position in a color spectrum (gradient) that I already have.

I thought this could be done doing an weighted arithmetic mean, but I can't get a proper solution.

The color selection is handled by a vector with a sum of each user choice by color. For example, if we have the colours black, purple, green and red, and the user selects black two times, purple none, green one and red 1 time, we have a selection vector like `[2, 0, 1, 1]`, and that will average a color somewhere between purple and green I guess - putting in a scale of `0.0 to 1.0` it should be near 0.5.

A simple pseudo-code algorithm would be great, but any direction to the right path is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to end up on a scale of 0 to 1, it seems like you'd need to assign each color a number on that scale to start out. So suppose black = 0, purple = 0.2, green = 0.4, and red = 0.6 ... and 0.8 and 1 for yellow and white, let's further imagine. Then the color selection vector in your example is [2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]. Dot-product that with [0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1] to get your "weighted color total," here 0.4 + 0.6 = 1, and divide by the component sum of the color selection vector, in this case 4. So the result is 0.25, purple with a hint of green. (I'm not clear on how you obtained "near 0.5.") But of course what color it comes out to depends on how you space out the values assigned to the respective colors.

That's how I'd do it. If that's what you're doing, then I'd be curious what leads you to think you're not getting a proper solution.

Comment: This is exactly what I missed, the dot product. You're right, it not even close to 0.5 :) thanks.